# Trouble adding elements to end of linked list

Tags: c++, debugging, linked-list

I am trying to add an element to the back of the linked list but it doesnt seem to add, can someone tell me what is wrong with my code thanks. My linked List is not empty

```
void LinkedList::Addelementfromback(VoidPtr horoscope)
{
   NodePtr temp = head;  

   while (temp != NULL)
   {
    temp=temp->next;
   }

    NodePtr element=new Node;

    element->data=horoscope;

    element->next=NULL;

    temp=element;
}
```

Comment: That function effectively does nothing at all, except leak memory.

Comment: @chris that is so helpful thanks, please learn from Pavel

Comment: @Computernerd: That's no way to talk to somebody who took the time, for free, on a weekend, to read your non-question and review your code for you. Please learn from... everyone else.

Comment: That would be why it was a quick comment. It leaves you a bit better off then having no clue why it isn't working, as you can then find out *why* it does nothing.

Comment: Let's make peace. 'non-question'? Sure it is an OK question, and even explains semantics of C assignment. 'quick comment'? Sure it is okay to provide a comment at the right context. It is not an answer. 'irony' requires careful formulation and a smiley, but otherwise it's just a comment, no need to pull out guns. Have a great Saturday, gentlemen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`temp` is a copy of the last `next` value, which is NULL.
You assign to a copy.

What you should have done, is stop one iteration earlier. Then do, `temp->next=element;`

To stop one iteration earlier, use: `while (temp->next != NULL)`

Comment: @Computernerd: http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: You will also need to assign to temp->next of course.